# Change rgb image color with hsv values with OpenCV, python

Tags: python, opencv

I have a task to change the red rectangle to blue with the given hsv parameters:
-0.3333, -0.05, -0.05

then save the new image.

I used the following site to demonstrate the blue square transform.
[HSV to RGB transform](https://codebeautify.org/hsv-to-rgb-converter)
So first of all I have to check the image hsv. Lets say e.g.
1, 1, 1

[image]

To transform it to blue I have to subtract the given parameters from the image hsv.

h: 1 - 0.3333 = 0.667 , s: 1 - 0.05 = 0.95, v: 1 - 0.05 = 0.95

[image]

[image]

[image]

I assume first I have to convert rbg image to hsv but I couldn't figure out how can I transform it to blue with the given parameters.

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('C:\projects\red.jpg')

hsv_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

cv2.imwrite('C:\projects\hsv_blue.jpg', hsv_image)

cv2.imshow('HSV image', hsv_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: 1) Why does it get bigger? 2) What do you need the input image for because the output appears to be defined without it?

Comment: @Mark Setchell Sorry for the misunderstanding both square are the same size. I need to use the input image and I have to transform its color because this is the task

Comment: Use ````cv.split()```` to get the single channels, subtract the given values for H, S, V (you'll need to handle overflow for values<0, ````convertTo()````  to a signed type first), and ````cv.merge()```` them back together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will work, 255 is 100% on OpenCV.

```
image = cv2.imread('img.png')
img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

img_hsv[:, :, 0] = (img_hsv[:, :, 0] - int(255 * 0.3333)) % 255
img_hsv[:, :, 1] = (img_hsv[:, :, 1] - int(255 * 0.05)) % 255
img_hsv[:, :, 2] = (img_hsv[:, :, 2] - int(255 * 0.05)) % 255

img_bgr = cv2.cvtColor(img_hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2RGB)
cv2.imwrite("modified_image.jpg", img_bgr)
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should identify the red square, make a mask to change the pixels colors and change it.

The code below might help, but I use opencv HSV color range ( H [0-180], S [0-255] , V [0-255] ). I could not understand your HSV parameters range.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#Load image
image = cv2.imread('redsquare.jpg')
image_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

#Define red square area
hsv_lower_red = np.array([150,50,70])
hsv_upper_red = np.array([180,255,255])
mask = cv2.inRange(image_hsv, hsv_lower_red, hsv_upper_red)

#Change red to blue
hsv_blue_color = np.uint8([[[120,255,255 ]]])
image_hsv[mask > 0] = hsv_blue_color

#Save results to file
image = cv2.cvtColor(image_hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
cv2.imwrite('bluesquare.jpg', image)
```

Comment: sorry it wasn't clear, I added more detailed description

Comment: It looks to me that you used this HSV parameters just because of your reference website. So, if it's not a problem, you could use opencv HSV format. My answer point to blue color as 120, 255, 255.